# AuthorizationState cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: dotnetopenauth

The implementation for authorization state in the [source](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/v4.3/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client/OAuth2/AuthorizationState.cs#L16) indicates that the authorization state should be serializable, but when I try to serialize the authorization state to store in my authentication ticket, I get an error saying that the implementation needs a parameterless constructor.

Snipped from the referenced source:

```
[Serializable]
public class AuthorizationState : IAuthorizationState {
    ...
    public AuthorizationState(IEnumerable<string> scopes = null) {
```

How I'm getting the state:

```
var Authorization = Client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
```

How I'm trying to serialize the state:

```
    public string Serialize(IAuthorizationState objectInstance)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectInstance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I ran a quick console app

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var can = new CanSerialize();
        var cant = new CantSerialize();

        var ser1 = can.Serialize();
        var ser2 = cant.Serialize();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CantSerialize
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public CantSerialize(int ID = 1)
    {
        id = ID;
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class CanSerialize
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    private CanSerialize()
    {
        id = 1;
    }
    public CanSerialize(int ID = 1)
    {
        id = ID;
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can the implementation have a default parameterless constructor? As the sample shows, it can be private if there is concern about having a public ctor.

In the meantime, I'm going to create a data transfer object to ferry the information back and forth between my authorization token and the state.

EDIT:
I've found that the JSON.net conversion works well:

```
var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Authorization);
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a, typeof(AuthorizationState));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the JSON.net conversion works well:

```
var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Authorization);
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a, typeof(AuthorizationState));
```